# Как с помощью метода изменить значение атрибута класса. Питон

Tags: python, ооп, классы, объекты

Метод `go()` должен
изменить `is_going` на `True` и принимать расстояние поездки, далее изменять показания
одометра(километраж).

```
class Car:
    
    def __init__ (self, owner, make, model, year, odometr = 0, is_going = False):
        self.owner = owner
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometr = odometr
        self.is_going = is_going

    def go(self):
        return self.is_going == True
        #delattr(self, 'is_going')
        #setattr(self, 'is_going', True)

    def stop(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Либо вы неясно высказались, либо выдумали проблему на пустом месте. Написать `self.is_going = True` пробовали?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Car:
    def __init__ (self, owner, make, model, year, odometr = 0, is_going = False):
        self.owner = owner
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometr = odometr
        self.is_going = is_going

    def go(self):
#        return self.is_going == True
        self.is_going = True
        
        #delattr(self, 'is_going')
        #setattr(self, 'is_going', True)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_going = False
#        pass

      
car = Car('owner', 'make', 'model', 'year')

print(car.is_going)
car.go()
print(car.is_going)
car.stop()
print(car.is_going)
```